# an example for Theorem2.6(Conway page 9)

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces

In Theorem 2.6 in Conway is say:If $M$ is a closed linear subspace of $H , h \in H$, and $f_{0}$ is the unique element of $M$ such that $\lVert h-f_{0} \rVert = dist(h,M)$, then $h-f_{0} \bot M$. Conversely, if $f_{0} \in M$ such that $h-f_{0} \bot M$, then $\lVert h-f_{0} \rVert=dist(h,M)$.This all of theorem!But I have an example for this theorem, That's why I started with this example, I suppose that $H= \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} $ and $ \big \langle x,y \big \rangle= \sum_{i=1}^{n} x(i) \cdot y(i)$. Hence  $\big \langle h-f_{0},f \big \rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{n} h_{i}-f_{0}(i) \cdot f(i)$. Now let $M=\{ [a,b] : a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \}$ be a closed( and convex) subset of $H$ and let $f_{0}=[(1, 1, \cdots, 1), (1, 1, \cdots, 1)]$, consequently $h-f_{0}=(h_{1}-1,h_{2}- 1, \cdots, h_{n}- 1)$. I want to show that $\big \langle h-f_{0},f \big \rangle=0$. Of course, maybe with a simpler example, you can say this theorem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: We are talking about the **orthogonal projection** on $M$ here! Why not take $H=\mathbb R^2$, $M=\{(x,0)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$ - the $x$-axis, and for $h=(x,y)$ you will have $f_0=(x,0)$ (projection of $h$ onto $x$-axis). Note $h-f_0=(0,y)\perp M$.

Comment: This is a good example, thank you. But I think $M= \{ (x,0) : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$

Comment: Typo corrected, thanks!